# What is the best method for farming for a Stone of Jordan?

Tags: diablo-ii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I maximize my chances of finding specific items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64621/how-can-i-maximize-my-chances-of-finding-specific-items)

I've heard that, due to the loot mechanics in Diablo 2, some areas are more likely to net you a Stone of Jordan than others.  What area or areas give you the best drop rate?

Does your character's level influence this?

Comment: I would recommend generalizing this to "How do I determine the best method for finding any specific item?" - keeping it this specific doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @IanPugsley Iirc, the best method varies depending on the ilvl of the drop you are interested in. Also, the SoJ is a bit of an unusual scenario in that it [was a mainstay of the economy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22688/why-did-stones-of-jordan-sojs-become-the-currency-at-one-point-in-diablo) at one point, and then became a key to summoning [uber Diablo](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Uber_Diablo).

Comment: It's fairly close to irrelevant at this point though - uber Diablo gets spawned on non-ladder with dupes and farmed on ladder, and runes run the economy. I don't think it's off-topic, but I think generalizing it could make it more useful.

Comment: Hrm.  I'd be willing to generalize it, but that would invalidate the answers already listed. Do you think it would be appropriate to ask it as a separate question, and then flag and request that a mod close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with either option (change or new/close), but the second seems cleaner.

Comment: More generalized question [posted here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64621/how-can-i-maximize-my-chances-of-finding-specific-items).

Comment: A question on this specific item in Diablo 2 is perfectly legitimate. The Stone of Jordan is an item which is often sought after in this game, and a very valuable item often used as a marker for what other items are worth. Simply asking how to find *any* item in Diablo 2 will not yield the same answer as asking where to find this specific item, though it would still be a good question. I am afraid that I do not understand the mentality of closing a legitimate question like this simply because it can be more generalized.

Comment: @Lemmings19 That was my original thought as well, but I believed, after the discussion with Ian Pugsley above, that a more general question would provide the information needed to determine the best spot for SoJ farming. After seeing the excellent answer that question received, I was dismayed to see that it actually *does not* provide information for finding SoJs.

Comment: @Beofett You might start off with a SoJ, and then decide that there are some very valuable runes that need to be covered as well. Attempting to cover specific items in a generalized question like that could keep going and going, breaking it down to many different uniques, runes, socketed items, etc. (all items which I think could have their own questions, as each answer will be different) and their answer would turn into a book. That is why I thought a question this specific held legitimacy, not to say that a more general question isn't useful as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, farming a [Stone of Jordan](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Stone_of_Jordan) isn't the most reliable, as it can take you some time.

Your character level does not affect what loot is dropped, only the monster's level. However, your [Magic Find](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Magic_Find) can greatly affect what loot is dropped.

If you are looking for this specific drop, [Nightmare](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Nightmare) [Andariel](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Andariel) (final boss of act 1, in [Nightmare difficulty](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Nightmare)) has the highest drop rate. She has a better chance of dropping rings than some other bosses, and she is the appropriate level to drop a Stone of Jordan instead of a different unique ring (there are fewer variations of rings that she can drop due to her level).

This said, you won't get nearly as much other loot just farming Nightmare Andariel. If you are looking to have a more beneficial farming experience whilst looking for a Stone of Jordan, I suggest farming a different boss, like [Hell](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Hell) Andariel, Nightmare [Mephisto](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Mephisto), or [Hell](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Hell) [Mephisto](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Mephisto). Though you will see a lower drop chance for this ring, you will see plenty of other useful loot while you are looking for it.

Be aware that looking for this specific drop, even off of Nightmare [Andariel](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Andariel), you may be killing her over a thousand times before you see this ring drop, **if** you see this ring drop.

Sources:

- Lots of personal Diablo II playtime.
- [Here](http://forums.d2jsp.org/topic.php?t=27012661) is a Stone of Jordan farming guide.
- And [another](https://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/the-stone-of-jordan-magic-find-guide-by-igor-potapov.146855/).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way [item levels](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Item_level) and drops work in Diablo 2, the best place to farm for an SoJ is nightmare Anduriel.

There are two reasons behind this:

1. Andariel has a high chance of dropping a ring.
2. By keeping the monster level just low enough to drop an SoJ, you reduce the chance of other 'clutter' such as higher level unique rings (such as BKs), and other unique items.

Your character's level does not affect the drop rate but the amount of Magic Find you have does.